# JetBrains Meta Programming System not working

Tags: mps

Whenever I try to run the batch script to run MPS, it opens for a split second then immediately closes.

Trying to run it via the command line gives me the following message: "Jetbrains/MPS was unexpected at this time."

I posted the question also on their forum, but I don't seem to get an answer, so maybe someone else had this problem as well.

EDIT: For clarification, I am using Windows 10 on 64 bits, and have tried both version 203.7148.1199 and version 202.8194.1069, installed via the toolbox app and via the standalone installer. I also want to mention that my system meets the requirements to run the program.

EDIT 2: I found out that it works but only if it is installed in the C drive, not in any other drive.

Comment: I had the same problem, and the issue was that I downloaded the batch script and all relevant files from my company and saved them in a folder other than the one in which MPS script was installed, thinking that the script would find the MPS installation folder no matter where it was. After moving the script and relevant files to the MPS installation folder, the script ran fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the path in which MPS was installed. Apparently, it's a bug that I just discovered and the characters '(' or ')' in the installation path make MPS just not run. Probably the bat script doesn't take them right into account or something.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what OS you are running, and which version of MPS you downloaded. If you used the generic package, you must at least copy the contents from the bin/<os> directory (e.g. bin/win) to the bin directory. Although the recommended way of running vanilla MPS is to download the platform specific package (Windows, Linux or Mac) and then run it from your normal starter (e.g. a menu like the Windows start menu).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28443872)

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell: While the first part of the answer does, in fact, ask for clarification, the second part of the question provides guidance on how to solve the problem. A good rule of thumb when reviewing answers is to ignore links or clarifying questions, and then evaluate what’s left over; if what’s left is an answer, mark it as being okay.

Comment: That said, Eugen, in the future it’d be preferable to leave the request for clarification as a comment, and focus your answer exclusively on your proposed solution. That will help avoid this type of confusion.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and the latest MPS version. I'll update my question to include these details, but I have already did what you said and it just simply doesn't work. I have tried both installing the package downloaded from their website and installing it via the toolbox app, but it just doesn't run. I have also tried the 2nd latest version and I get the same issue.